# How to detect GameScene touches from another file using swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, touchesbegan

I am currently making a game in sprite kit. In the game, there are random shapes and objects on the ground that you can pick up and rotate and stack on to one another to build up to a target height. Once the target height is reached you move on to the next level. Each object and shape is created in a swift file separate from the GameScene under the SKNode class. I am able to pick the object up and move it around on the screen using the touchesBegan, moved, and ended methods in the node. While I'm holding on to the object I would like to be able to tap and hold the screen with a second finger anywhere on the screen that rotates the object until the finger is let go, so, the first finger grabs and hold the object while the other finger rotates it. The problem is that I have found it almost impossible for the SKNode to detect a touch outside of the actual node. Below is the code I have used for the SKNode. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class GameObjects: SKNode {

    var object: SKSpriteNode
    var action: () -> Void

    init(objectImage: String, buttonAction: () -> Void ){

        object = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: objectImage)
        action = buttonAction

        let object1Texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "object1")
        object1Texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

        let size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
        object.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: object1Texture, size: size)

        object.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        object.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
        object.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true

        super.init()

        userInteractionEnabled = true
        addChild(object)

    }


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in (touches ) {

            let location: CGPoint = touch.locationInNode(self)

            let moveUp = SKAction.moveToY(location.y + 200, duration: 0.05)
            object.runAction( moveUp)

        }

        object.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        object.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in (touches ) {

            let location: CGPoint = touch.locationInNode(self)

            object.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
            object.physicsBody?.dynamic = true

            object.position.x = location.x
            object.position.y = location.y + 200
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

            object.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
            object.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    }

}
```

Comment: Why you are subclassing `SKNode` and then adding a `SKSpriteNode` to the node instead of subclassing `SKSpriteNode`? Also, if you handle the touches in GameScene, you'll have only one touch handler (instead of one per subclass) _and_ you'll be able to detect touches outside of the node/sprite.

Comment: Yes but I need the subclassed node in particular to know that I touched the GameScene

Comment: If you touch the screen in a location that doesn't contain a sprite, the scene will be returned by `nodeAtPoint`. This will happen in `touchesBegan` in GameScene but not in your subclasses.